# How to beep in vim

Tags: vim

Is there any way to explicitly request vim to beep, preferably without having to run external commands?

The reason is that I often run commands (like `:make`) that take quite long, so I start doing something else, but than I need to be alerted to the fact that the task finished. So there is no error that would cause vim to beep, but I can run arbitrary command, so I need some command that would make it beep (ok, with running external program it's doable, but I'd prefer more portable method).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes:

```
:set novisualbell
:set errorbells
:exe "normal \<Esc>"
```

For more information see:

- [`:help beep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#beep)
- [`:help 'errorbells'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27errorbells%27)
- [`:help :echoerr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#:echoerr)

Comment: @JanHudec Exceedingly belatedly, the `:execute` is necessary so you can use a string constant containing an `Esc` character. `:normal \<Esc>` will instead perform the equivalent of pressing the 6 keystrokes `\ < E s c >`, which may or may not be an error in normal mode, depending on your config. `:normal! \<esc>` will work in current versions of Vim regardless of config (because ignoring mappings backslash does nothing on its own), but it's a bit of a roundabout way of going about the task.

Comment: According to `:help 'errorbells'`, "the bell will be used always for […] hitting <Esc> in Normal mode)," so `:set errorbells` does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Print the Bell character (Ctrl-G). On Windows `echo ^G` will cause a beep. Depending on your terminal setup it also works on Linux.

Comment: In GUI version it simply prints cyan '^G'.

Answer (score 1):

Here's @johnsyweb-supports-our-mods's answer, with more edge cases taken care of and wrapped in a reusable command:

```
command -bar Bell call s:Bell()
function s:Bell()
  const l:belloff = &g:belloff
  const l:visualbell = &g:visualbell
  const l:mode = mode()
  const l:visual =
  \   l:mode ==? 'v' || l:mode ==# "\<C-V>"
  \|| l:mode ==? 's' || l:mode ==# "\<C-S>"
  try
    set belloff-=esc
    set novisualbell
    if l:visual
      execute "normal! \<Esc>"
    endif
    execute "normal! \<Esc>"
  finally
    let &g:belloff = l:belloff
    let &g:visualbell = l:visualbell
    if l:visual
      normal! gv
    endif
  endtry
endfunction
```

Explanation:

- `set belloff-=esc` makes hitting <kbd>Escape</kbd> in Normal mode ring the bell.
- `set novisualbell` makes the bell audible.
- Hitting <kbd>Escape</kbd> in Visual or Select mode simply returns us to Normal mode without ringing the bell, so we need to ensure we are in Normal mode first with `execute "normal! \<Esc>"`.
- `execute "normal! \<Esc>"` rings the bell.
- `normal! gv` returns us to Visual or Select mode if we started in one of those modes.